# Rank of smooth distribution

Tags: vector-bundles

Let M is smooth manifold. suppose D is smooth distribution of smooth vector bundle $\pi:E \longrightarrow M$.
Why the rank D is lower semi-continuous function on M?

Comment: What do you mean by a distribution of a vector bundle? Do you mean a vector subbundle? The usual definition of distribution is a vector subbundle of the tangent bundle, but that doesn't fit the question.

Comment: @BenMcKay this approach is intended: for a vector bundle $(E,\pi)$ a distribution D in E is assigns to each $x\in M$ a vector subspace $D_{x} \subset E_{x} $. If dimension of $D_{x} $ ,called rank of distribution at x , is independent of x, we call the distribution is regular. A distribution that is smooth and regular is subbundle.

Comment: What does it mean that $D$ is smooth? Does it mean that $D$ is a smooth submanifold of $E$?

Comment: I think here a distribution is the span of a finite set of sections.

Comment: @BenMcKay smooth distribution mean for any $x \in M $ and $ v_{0} \in D_{x}$, there is a smooth local section v of E such that v(x)=v_{0}

Comment: The problem is local, so we can assume that $E$ is trivial. Then for each point $x_0$, take a maximal collection of local smooth sections which are linearly independent at $x_0$. They are also, by continuity, linearly independent at any point $x$ nearby $x_0$, and span a subspace of $D_x$. This is not suitable for mathoverflow.

Comment: Sorry about that